# Evaluating expression in angularjs directive's compile function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building a custom directive that will display different HTML elements based on an attribute value.

For example

```
   <my-directive show="text" value="123" /> <!-- this displays a text box -->
   <my-directive show="boolean" value="true" /> <!-- this shows a checkbox -->
```

I am trying to use the compile function to only add the necessary DOM elements.  Everything works if I specify the values for `show` and `value` as text, but when I try to set them via an angular expression it doesn't work.

For example

```
   <my-directive show="myObject.type" value="myObject.value" />
```

How can I make the results of the angular expression available to my compile function.

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(el, attrs) {
      if (attrs.show == 'text')
        el.replaceWith(textTemplate)
      else if (attrs.show == 'number')
        el.replaceWith(numTemplate)
      else if (attrs.show == 'boolean')
        el.replaceWith(boolTemplate)
      else if (attrs.show == 'timezone')
        el.replaceWith(tzTemplate)
      else if (attrs.show == 'datetime')
        el.replaceWith(dtTemplate)
      else if (attrs.show == 'date')
        el.replaceWith(dateTemplate)
      else if (attrs.show == 'time')
        el.replaceWith(timeTemplate)
      else
        console.log("no input type matched "+attrs.show);  // this always fires, with value 'myObject.type'

      },
      link: function() { .... }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Until you hit the linking functions you do not have access to both the element attributes and the scope to be able to resolve the expression to the value on the scope.

Comment: If I write like this way <my-directive show="text" value="hello" />, it works. It will show an input[text] box.

Comment: Yes, because you do not need the scope to resolve the variables. Basically it is impossible to access the scope to resolve variables on the scope within the compile function. Have you tried moving your code to the Link function instead of the compile function?

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of a place where you can make use of [directives isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  Creating an isolate scope has another major feature, it will make the directive more re-usable.

```
directive('myDirective', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    show: '=show',
    value: '=value'
  },
  compile: function(el, attrs) {
       if ($scope.show === 'text'
       ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But scope is not injected yet when compiling the DOM. Am I right?